# How to regex convert text input file with "++++", "+++" as group separators to CSV or JSON

Tags: node.js, regex

I have a file formatted like this:

```
03.12.2020  ++++baz;bar;++bik;
04.12.2020  +++bar;
05.12.2020  ++++baz;bar;bur,jojo;+++bik;buch;+pac;
```

It follows the format:

date, tab, "++++", list of keywords with magnitude 4 with ";"after each keyword, "+++" list of keywords with magnitude 3 with ";"after each keyword etc.

It the specific magnitude does not exist the section is omitted for example (+++keyword_with_magnitude_3;+keyword_with_magnitude_1;another_keyword_with_magnitude_1;)

I need to convert it to:
date, keyword; magnitude

For example from:

```
03.12.2020  ++++baz;bar;++bik;
```

to

```
03.12.2020, baz, 4
03.12.2020, bar, 4
03.12.2020, bik, 2
```

Regex `^(\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\d\d\t)\+\+\+\+([^\+\r]+)` finds only the lines with "four's and nothing else

EDIT1: I could drop it into NodeJS if it is easier. I don't know how to split the lines while keeping the date as a first thing in each lane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
const text = `03.12.2020  ++++baz;bar;++bik;
04.12.2020  +++bar;
05.12.2020  ++++baz;bar;bur,jojo;+++bik;buch;+pac;`
for (const line of text.split(/[\r\n]+/)) {
  console.log(`=== Processing '${line}' ===`);
  [_, date, data] = line.match(/^(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}) +(.+)/);
  const matches = data.matchAll(/(\+*)([^;,]+)/g)
  let magnitude = 0;
  for (const m of matches) {
    if (m[1].length > 0) { magnitude = m[1].length; }
    const val = m[2];
    console.log(`${date}, ${val}, ${magnitude}`);
  }
}
```

**Notes**:

- `.split(/[\r\n]+/)` splits the text into lines (you might probably deal with it in a different way, I just assumed you have the input as a single string)
- `[_, date, data] = line.match(/^(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}) +(.+)/);` fills out `date` and `data` with the Group 1 and Group 2 values: the first group captures the data and the second group matches any text after the first spaces (can even be written as `line.match(/^(\S+)\s+(\S.*)/);`)
- Since `data` contains the elements we need to split, it is matched with `(\+*)([^;,]+)`, Group 1 now contains zero or more pluses, and the second group contains one or more chars other than comma and semi-colon.
- Iterating over the above matches, `magnitude` is re-assigned once Group 1 (the pluses) is not empty. The final result is a concatenation of date, value and magnitude.

Comment: Works like a charm. 
Now I need to dig through this to fully understand it.
Lesson for the future - I should have code it in JS from the beginning instead trying to solve it with find/replace in text editor

Comment: @pall04 Yes, some problems cannot be solved with a single plain regex. Although there are really nice and cool tricks (see my [Notepad++ conditional replacement YouTube demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hg_UNKwZXak&t=1s), for example), in cases like this there is no other way than a bit of code.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind running few steps, this might work:

- run all of the next steps till no changes are made (assuming that global replace is not available)
- distribute the magnitudes:

Find: `(\++)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[;,]([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`

Replace: `\1\2;\1\3`

- move to a new line each keyword, by copying the date

Find: `^(\d\d\.\d\d.\d\d\d\d)(\s+)(\+*)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[;,](\+*)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(.*)$`

Replace: `\1 \3\4;\n\1 \5\6\7`

- reformat the lines to have the pluses as a digit after the keyword (1 plus)

Find: `^(\d\d\.\d\d.\d\d\d\d)(\s+)(\+{1})([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[;,]`

Replace: `\1,\4,1`

- reformat the 2 pluses

Find: `^(\d\d\.\d\d.\d\d\d\d)(\s+)(\+{2})([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[;,]`

Replace: `\1,\4,2`

- reformat the 3 pluses

Find: `^(\d\d\.\d\d.\d\d\d\d)(\s+)(\+{3})([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[;,]`

Replace: `\1,\4,3`

- reformat the 4 pluses

Find: `^(\d\d\.\d\d.\d\d\d\d)(\s+)(\+{4})([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[;,]`

Replace: `\1,\4,4`

Empty lines you remove with: `(\r?\n)(\r?\n)+` => `\1`

Lines with only dates you remove with: `^(\d\d\.\d\d.\d\d\d\d)(\s*)(\r?\n)` => nothing

Comment: Does not work at `(\++)([a-zA-Z]+);([a-zA-Z]+)` because there is unknown number of keywords (between 1 and 8) and not two.

Comment: Please share your input data, so I can take a look. For the data you have supplied in the question it does work. This pattern matches pluses followed by a word, then semicolon, then another word. The idea is to get the pluses from the previous word, and to copy them to the next word, which does not have any pluses. The number of keywords plays no role for this pattern.

Comment: I would have to anonymize it heavily. There is 12 keywords and each can have value from 0 to 4. When it is 0 it does not show on the list. If it is between 1-4 it does. So the worst case scenario would be:

`date ++++k1;k2;k3;k4;k5;k6;k7;k8;k9;k10;k11;+k12;`

I think I figured it out at least partially

I run `^(\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4})(.*)(\t|;)(\+.*)` replace to `\1\2\3\n\1\t\4` a number of times and the deleted the lines that had only date or empty line.

Comment: The pattern works by running it 12 times. Each time will transfer the pluses to the next keyword. I know that its a lot of runs, but the regular expressions are not so powerful. In your question there was no digits in the keyword. That is the problem. I will upgrade the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Find:
`^(\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4})(.*)(\t|;)(\+.*)`

Replace:
`\1\2\3\n\1\t\4`

run this 3 times

- Remove empty lines and lines that have only date and no data after.

Find: `^(\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4})\t(\+\+\+\+)(.+)`

Replace: `\1,\3,4`

Find: `^(\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4})\t(\+\+\+)(.+)`

Replace: `\1,\3,3`

Find: `^(\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4})\t(\+\+)(.+)`

Replace: `\1,\3,2`

Find: `^(\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4})\t(\+)(.+)`

Replace: `\1,\3,1`